# Is there a compact way to replace a placeholder char in a string with a random element from a list?

Tags: python

Consider arbitrary strings in which the character `@` represents a placeholder char.

For example:
`"@ has bought 8 apples today"`
`"@ and @ are together for 10 years"`
`"If @ wouldn't have told me that, I would have never known that you got in touch with @.`

Now, in addition I have a list: `names = ['Peter', 'James', 'Claire', 'Julia']`

Finally, I want to iterate over a random string from my string list and replace every `@` with a random element from the `names` list. Although, it should not happen that the same name is picked twice.

Ugly solution (Pseudo-Code):

```
names = some_names
list_of_arbitrary_strings = some_strings
while True:
    raw_str = random.choice(list_of_arbitrary_strings)
    processed_str = ""
    temp_names = random.shuffle(names)
    for chr in current_str:
       if chr == "@":
           chr = temp_names.pop()
       processed_str += chr
    print(processed_str)
    input('Press any key to continue')
```

Is there something better that I could do (library calls, changing the structure of my strings, ...)?

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurrences of @ with the same random name in the same string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with `random.shuffle`:

```
import re, random
def rep_char(s, l):
   random.shuffle(l)
   l = iter(l)
   return re.sub('@', lambda _:next(l), s)

names = ['Peter', 'James', 'Claire', 'Julia']
vals = ["@ has bought 8 apples today", "@ and @ are together for 10 years", "If @ wouldn't have told me that, I would have never known that you got in touch with @."]
result = [rep_char(i, names) for i in vals]
```

Output:

```
['Julia has bought 8 apples today', 'Claire and Julia are together for 10 years', "If Julia wouldn't have told me that, I would have never known that you got in touch with Claire."]
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I think I was not clear enough in my question. The same name shouldn't be drawn twice in a single string but for each string in the string array, the names array is reset. For example: "James has bought..." and "James and John are..." can happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the placeholder by `{}` and simply use format and [sample](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample)

```py
import random

NAMES = ['Peter', 'James', 'Claire', 'Julia']
STRINGS = [
    "{} has bought 8 apples today",
    "{} and {} are together for 10 years",
    "If {} wouldn't have told me that, I would have never known that you got in touch with {}."
]


def replace(text, names):
    return text.format(*random.sample(names, text.count("{}")))


for text in STRINGS:
    print(replace(text, NAMES))
```